# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar las clases del modelo de datos y a su vez las tablas de la DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

La aplicacion es Asp.Net Core

Actualice mi modelo de datos  usando una DB pre existente  y utilize este comando:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=90.300.117.255;Database=DBApp;User Id=usario2021;password=enero2021;;Trusted_Connection=False;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force -Context ClaseContext
```

Ahora tengo problemas cuando necesito agregar una tabla nueva a la Db y usarla en mi aplicación dentro del contexto de datos.
¿Qué método debería usar para actualizar en la db y en el modelo de mi app?

Si uso comandos como `Add-Migrations` ; `Update-DataBase`  *me devuelve el error de que ya existen las Tablas y si creo la tabla en Db y uso el mismo comando me duplica las clases que genera.*

**¿Cómo puedo resolver este dilema?**

Existe algun comando que agregue solo las tablas nuevas?

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta es usar Migrations para no estar recreando tus modelos, porque si modificas tus modelos se van a perder cada que los recreas.
Cuando creas tu migration inicial, elimina lo que esté dentro del Up(), según yo ahí debería estar la creación de las tablas y por eso te da el error de que ya existen.
Si lo eliminas no va a intentar crearlas y no te dará el error al actualizar la base de datos.

Comment: Emmanuel LG ...revise y el metodo Up() esta vacio ...                              protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

Comment: Algo está mal ahí entonces. La función Up debería tener la construcción de todo tu esquema de la base de datos que tienes actualmente.
Trata eliminando migrations y volviendo a agregarla. remove-migration y add-migration.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la respuesta de: ***Emmanuel LG***

**1er Paso**
Elimine todas la migraciones existentes.

**2do Paso**
Use este comando: `Add-Migration Initial  -Context NombreContexto`

**3er Paso**
Use este comando: `Update-DataBase -Context NombreContexto`